# Determine winner based on taking king

Tags: analysis, chess-variants

I've been asked my friend about enable take king to determine the winner..

who's the winner if the condition like this?? (some Fide rule should necessary)

```
[FEN "7k/6r1/7p/8/8/2B1q3/6N1/6K1 - - - 0 0 "] 

1. Ng2xQe3 Rg7xKg1 2. Bc3xKh8
```

Comment: Intuitively, black would win, because he takes the white king first, and the game ends at that point.

Comment: Based on your comment on Tony Ennis's answer, you are playing a variant where taking king is legal. If that is the case, how would others know the rules of your or your friend's variant?

Comment: I think the comment from @JiK is spot on, and there isn't really a clear, answerable question here. I'm going to close this question; it can be reopened if it is edited into something more suitable. For what it's worth, there is a somewhat related earlier question: http://chess.stackexchange.com/q/1515/167

Comment: thanks @[EdDean](http://chess.stackexchange.com/users/167/ed-dean), from the [Q&A](http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/1515/bizarre-pin-rule-pinned-pieces-do-not-attack), I realize that were chess variant.. as @[JamesChristopher](http://chess.stackexchange.com/users/1580/james-christopher) said, **Black** definitely **won**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The knight move is illegal since one may not expose one's king to check.  That the rook is pinned is of no relevance.

Comment: yes, I've consider that, but in this case, taking king is legal..

Comment: In chess, the king cannot be captured, so I don't know what you mean.

Comment: thanks.. I've found [the answer](http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/1515/bizarre-pin-rule-pinned-pieces-do-not-attack).. may be you should read it first.. ^^

Comment: It's a variant.  It isn't standard chess.  You can make up any rules that please you in that case.