# What rule is this?

Tags: rules

In the following position, I am trying to play Rxd8, but it is not allowed.  What is the rule that disallows Rxd8?p

```
[FEN "1r1r1bk1/5p2/p3p1pp/1p2P3/B1p2P2/K2R4/P1P4P/3R4 w - - 0 1"]
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about chess in general, it's not about rules. But rather it's about a particular move in a particular game that a player did not see

Comment: Now that the asker has received the answer he's looking for, I feel this question should be closed

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your king on a3 is in check from the bishop on f8. When you are in check, you must move your king, capture the checking piece, or interpose a piece to block the check.

Comment: Cant believe I did not see that :-D, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The only move you can do with your rook is Rd6 closing Bf8+

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add a comment to the first answer, which is as precise as it can be, but I have no enough reputation, so I'll dare to add an extra note here:

Someone could argue (not Marius, who already showed his agreement with dfan's answer) that after Rd8 white's the bishop in f8 can't move because it's pinned by the white rook, and the way to refute that argument is that then Ba3, taking the white king, just finishes the game.

Comment: But capturing the king is an illegal move, kings can't be captured. A better argument would be that the rules say that pinned pieces still give check.

Comment: Precisely what I want to explain is why the "pinned pieces still give check" rule works, using more general rules (ie, the game is finished once one of the kigns is captured). Maybe I should have written it like this: In the case capturing the kings were allowed, you can't let your king to be attacked by an enemy pinned piece, because the pinned piece could capture your king in the next move, finishing the game.

Comment: +1 [My answer](http://chess.stackexchange.com/a/1517/86) to [Bizarre pin rule: pinned pieces do not attack](http://chess.stackexchange.com/q/1515/86) is along these lines.