# Is it possible for a white piece to deliver check to the black king, but for black's counter move to result in white getting checkmated?

Tags: checkmate, check

Is it possible for a white piece to deliver check to the black king, but for black's counter move to result in white getting checkmated?

Has this happened in games between top players?

Comment: *Has this happened in games between top players?* Highly unlikely. Such scenario is easily foreseeable because the move sequence is forced. Therefore top player would resign.

Comment: http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chesscollection?cid=1009425

Comment: @DagOskarMadsen You should post this as an answer! It precisely answers the second question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can find some examples in the following game collection: [Games where check is answered with checkmate](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chesscollection?cid=1009425).

Among those games, [Nigel Short vs Alexander Morozevich](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1254278), Russia - The Rest of the World (2002) is the only one that meets the qualification *top players*. This was a rapid game.

The most entertaining example is the following:

```
[FEN ""]
[Event "Philadelphia (m/7)"]
[Site "Philadelphia (m/7)"]
[Date "1945.??.??"]
[Result "0-1"]
[White "NN"]
[Black "Winkelman"]
[ECO "C29"]

1.e4 e5 2.Nc3 Nf6 3.f4 d5 4.fxe5 Nxe4 5.Qf3 Nc6 6.Bb5 Bc5
7.Nxe4 dxe4 8.Qxe4 O-O 9.Ne2 Re8 10.Bxc6 bxc6 11.Qxc6 Rxe5
12.Qxa8 Rxe2+ 13.Kd1 Bg4 14.Qxd8+ Re8# 0-1
```

There are also some additional examples in Edward Winter's Chess Notes: [4130](http://www.chesshistory.com/winter/winter18.html#4130._Check_and_mate), [4135](http://www.chesshistory.com/winter/winter18.html#4135._Check_and_mate_C.N._4130).

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it can happen.

```
[FEN "rk2K3/1q5r/8/8/4Q3/8/8/8 w - - 1 1"]

1.Qxb7+ Kxb7#
```

It probably won't happen in games between strong players because they'll resign when checkmate is inevitable.

Comment: Could you please provide the correct board?

Comment: I got it now...

Answer (score 6):

Could there be another example here? http://www.futilitycloset.com/2010/06/09/intercepted/
or is it checkmate followed by checkmate?

Comment: Yes, that is an example, regardless of your view on who gets checkmated. (Note that it is not really a matter of opinion. En passant, just like any other move, is illegal when the player is checkmated. E.g. from the final position, it is Black's turn, and he captures White's King before White can capture his. See [my post here](http://chess.stackexchange.com/a/1517/86).)

Comment: Totally agree with you anyway. Just thought the link was amusing.

Answer (score 2):

```
[Event "?"]
[Site "?"]
[Date "????.??.??"]
[Round "?"]
[White "?"]
[Black "?"]
[Result "*"]
[FEN "8/8/8/8/8/2k5/2q5/K1B5 w - - 0 1"]

1.Bb2+ Qxb2# *
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a check that forces a checkmate reply:

```
[fen "R3q3/r7/8/Rp5n/2P3Q1/1p3Kb1/N4RBP/2rkr3 w - - 0 119"]

1. Nc3+ Rxc3#
```

(from a [generated game with worst moves possible](https://lichess.org/broadcast/the-worst-chess-tournament/round-10/zWF330Yj/G7cEA1lK#236)).