# Could the black king move to C5?

Tags: checkmate

[image]

Could the black king move to C5?

Comment: related: https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/1515/bizarre-pin-rule-pinned-pieces-do-not-attack?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is checkmate. Even if Pb4 is pinned, it still controls square c5, preventing the black king to move there.

Check rules 3.9.1 and 3.9.2 of the [laws](http://fide.com/fide/handbook.html?id=208&view=article) of chess.

> 3.9.1 
>   The king is said to be 'in check' if it is attacked by one or more of the opponent's pieces, **even if such pieces are constrained from moving to the square occupied by the king because they would then leave or place their own king in check**.
>
> 3.9.2
>   No piece can be moved that will either expose the king of the same colour to check or leave that king in check.

(emphasis mine)

1...Kc5 is illegal.